# Naturality in all three arguments for Tensor-Hom adjunction in symmetric closed monoidal categories

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a symmetric closed monoidal category. This means in particular that for every fixed object $B \in \mathcal{C}$ the functor $-\otimes B$ has a right adjoint $[B,-]$, i.e. for all $A,B,C$ we have an isomorphism $$ \Phi: \mathcal{C}(A\otimes B,C) \overset{\cong}\longrightarrow \mathcal{C}(A,[B,C]), $$ natural in $A$ and $C$.

It is now claimed here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category under '2.Definitions - Symmetric closed monoidal category' that this isomorphism is natural in *all three* arguments.

On first sight it seems this should follow easily by somehow involving the symmetry on the left side but i am not able to proof it.

Does this even follow from the outset or do we have to assume it additionally?

EDIT:

For my question to even make sense we would first have to assemble all the functors $[B,-]$ into a functor $[-,-]:\mathcal{C}^{op}\times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$.

It turns out that this can be done in a unique way such that $\Phi$ is then natural in all three arguments.

To see this let $f:B\to B'$ in $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ (i.e. $f:B'\to B$ in $\mathcal{C}$) and $g:C \to C'$. Furthermore let $Y$ denote the Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}^\wedge$ and $Y^{-1}$ its inverse defined on the image of $Y$.

We have a natural transformation $$f^*g_* : \mathcal{C}(-\otimes B,C) \to \mathcal{C}(-\otimes B',C')$$ and by conjugation with $\Phi$ we obtain $$ \Phi f^*g_* \Phi^{-1}: [B,C]^\wedge \to [B',C']^\wedge.$$
Applying $Y^{-1}$ gives a morphism $[B,C] \overset{[f,g]}\longrightarrow [B',C']$ and this clearly defines a functor $[-,-]:\mathcal{C}^{op}\times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$.

By construction of $[-,-]$, $\Phi$ is now natural in all arguments. Furthermore, fixing the first argument of $[-,-]$ gives back the functors we started with.

I guess this answers my original question. But now a new one arises. If we already start with a bifunctor $[-,-]: \mathcal{C}^{op} \times \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ such that for every fixed $B$, $[B,-]$ is right adjoint to $-\otimes B$ does it then follow that it is isomorphic to the one constructed above? This is equivalent to asking if $\Phi$ is natural in all arguments in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to symmetry, being true for every monoidal closed category, and isn't an additional assumption.
Instead, it is a special case of a result on "adjunctions with a parameter":

Let $F : \mathcal A × \mathcal B → \mathcal C$ be a bifunctor, and denote with $F_B : \mathcal A → \mathcal C$ the functor $F(-, B)$ for every $B ∈ \mathcal B$. If every $F_B$ is left adjoint to a $G_B : \mathcal C → \mathcal A$ via
$$φ^B_{AC} : \mathrm{Hom}(F_BA, C) ≅ \mathrm{Hom}(A, G_BC),$$
then there exists a unique functor $G : \mathcal B^{\mathrm{op}} × \mathcal C → \mathcal A$ such that $G_B = G(B, -)$, and $φ$ is natural in $B$ too.

You can find the result and a proof in Mac Lane's Categories for the Working Mathematician.

So as you can see, $[B, -]$'s assemble into a single bifunctor automatically, but note that this functor ("internal hom") will be contravariant in its first argument, just like the usual hom functor is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited the question just before i read it. This also answers my follow up question. I guess my pitfall was that i tried using symmetry to prove it first.

Comment: The referenced result from [*Categories for the Working Mathematician*](http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/~ebatista/2016-2/maclanecat.pdf) is Chapter 4, Section 7, Theorem 3.