Compatibility of adjunctions for closed monoidal category
If $\mathcal V$ is braided monoidal closed, meaning that for any object $A$ the functor $-\otimes A$ admits a right adjoint $[A,-]$, then $\mathcal V$ is enriched over itself by letting $\mathcal V(A,B)=[A,B]$ (as well as unit and compositions, defined via the adjunctions). I wonder whether by demanding nothing else we get nonetheless an interplay between these different adjunctions. For example, for a morphism $f\colon A\to B$, one can consider
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
C @>{\eta^A}>> \mathcal V(A,C\otimes A)\\
@V{\eta^B}VV @VV{[A,C\otimes f]}V\\
\mathcal V(B,C\otimes B) @>{[f,C\otimes B]}>> \mathcal V(A,C\otimes B)
\end{CD}
Does it commute? I really can't see how to use triangular identities in order to relate the two different units... If not, does it commute at least in the case where $A=\mathbb 1$ is the monoidal unit?
Thank you so much in advance

The diagram commutes; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1928465/naturality-in-all-three-arguments-for-tensor-hom-adjunction-in-symmetric-closed (the extranaturality of the unit should follow from the naturality of the Hom-isomorphism in the "$A$" argument)

Oh, this is a good question. The answer generalises significantly to the enriched setting too (at least in the $\mathscr{V}$ symmetric case; looking at my own proofs I'd suspect a lot goes out of the window in the braided case, e.g. formulation of $\mathsf{C}^{\mathsf{op}}$ is less possible).
A good exercise for ordinary category theory (it involves tricky coherence-chasing and some effort in even stating carefully for enriched category theory) is the following:

A family of adjunctions $L:\mathsf{C}\times\mathsf{D}\to\mathsf{E},R:\mathsf{C}^{\mathsf{op}}\times\mathsf{E}\to\mathsf{D}$ with parameter in $\mathsf{C}$, i.e. $L(\varsigma,-)\dashv R(\varsigma,-)$ for all $\varsigma\in\mathsf{C}$), has that the choice of adjunction isomorphisms $\mathsf{E}(L(\varsigma,\partial),\xi)\cong\mathsf{D}(\partial,R(\varsigma,\xi))$ is natural in the parameter $\varsigma$ (thereby forming what I call a "fully natural" or "strong" parametric adjunction) if and only if the unit and counit of the adjunction are wedges and cowedges respectively; that is, if and only if for all $\partial\in\mathsf{D}$ the unit maps $\eta^\varsigma_\partial:\partial\to R(\varsigma,L(\varsigma,\partial))$ form a wedge over $R(-,L(-,\partial)):\mathsf{C}^{\mathsf{op}}\times\mathsf{C}\to\mathsf{D}$ and a similar statement for the counit.

This exactly specialises to an answer to your question; assuming you've defined your closed monoidal adjunction appropriately naturally (if not, you can change how $\mathscr{V}(-,-)$ works as a functor) then your diagram commutes.
Note that in what Riehl/Fosco call a "tensor-cotensor-hom" context, the parametric tensor-hom-cotensor adjunctions are fully natural (this isn't explicitly stated, often, since people just write $\cong$ but it is true. If it is not clearly true, then you should check it to make sure your situation really is a tensor-hom-cotensor context!). It is worth noting that if your parametric adjunction isn't fully natural, you can change the definition of, say, $R$ to make it so, in a unique way.
